# How to correct the code formatting settings in eclipse?

Tags: formatting, eclipse-cdt

I am actively using code formatting in eclipse (right click->source->format), after that a window would pop up asking me to format the whole file or the highlighted fragment. At some point, I accidentally clicked "remember the selection" and that window never came up again.
To clarify, this is CubeIDE, based on eclipse, C/C++.

Where can I fix the settings to make this window appear again?

Comment: For what language? Each editor provides its own formatter and preferences for formatting.

Comment: To clarify, this is CubeIDE, based on eclipse, C/C++.

Comment: [In the preferences in _C/C++_ there is a button to clear 'do not show again' for all dialogs](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_c_pref.htm). Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Unfortunately, the button on this tab does not reset the desired setting

Answer (score 0):

Found it. This is where the setting is:

[image]